# Quantidade de registro por Data MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Eu tenho o seguinte cenario.

Tenho uma tabela de vendas, lá existe um campo `data_vendas` (datetime) e um campo `cliente_id`

Outra tabela clientes, com os campos `id`, `nome`, `data_cadastro` etc.

O que preciso fazer é via SQL, por exemplo, dentro do mês de JUNHO, as vendas que tiveram.

So que a informação que preciso é quantos clientes compraram no mesmo de JUNHO e que tenha se cadastrado a no maximo 1 mês. E quantos clientes compraram dentro do mesmo de junho, que se cadastraram a um mes atras.

Answer (score -1):

A consulta retornará o total de vendas ( `totalVendas` ), o total de compras de usuários cadastrados no mês anterior que compraram esse mês ( `totalVendasCadastroAnterior` ) e o total de compras de usuários cadastrados no mês atual que compraram esse mês ( `totalVendasCadastroAtual` ).

SQL:

```
SELECT
    COUNT( * ) totalVendas,
    SUM(
        CASE WHEN
            ( MONTH( c.data_cadastro ) = 5 AND YEAR( c.data_cadastro ) = 2016 )
        THEN 1
        ELSE 0
        END
        ) totalVendasCadastroAnterior,
    SUM(
        CASE WHEN
            ( MONTH( c.data_cadastro ) = 6 AND YEAR( c.data_cadastro ) = 2016 )
        THEN 1
        ELSE 0
        END
        ) totalVendasCadastroAtual
FROM vendas v
JOIN clientes c
    ON c.id = v.cliente_id
WHERE MONTH( v.data_vendas ) = 6 AND YEAR( v.data_vendas ) = 2016
```

Um exemplo da query com PHP:

```
<?php
// Configurações
$config = [
    'DB_NAME' => 'db',
    'DB_USER' => 'user',
    'DB_PASS' => 'senha',
    'MES_DADOS' => 6,
    'ANO_DADOS' => 2016,
];

$prevMonth = $config['MES_DADOS'] > 1 ? $config['MES_DADOS'] - 1 : $config['MES_DADOS'] + 11;

try
{
    // Abre conexão
    $con = new PDO( "mysql:host=localhost;dbname={$config['DB_NAME']}", $config['DB_USER'], $config['DB_PASS'] );
    // Executa query
    $stmt = $con->prepare( 'SELECT
                                COUNT( * ) totalVendas,
                                SUM(
                                    CASE WHEN
                                        ( MONTH( c.data_cadastro ) = :prevMonth AND YEAR( c.data_cadastro ) = :year )
                                    THEN 1
                                    ELSE 0
                                    END
                                    ) totalVendasCadastroAnterior,
                                SUM(
                                    CASE WHEN
                                        ( MONTH( c.data_cadastro ) = :month AND YEAR( c.data_cadastro ) = :year )
                                    THEN 1
                                    ELSE 0
                                    END
                                    ) totalVendasCadastroAtual
                            FROM vendas v
                            JOIN clientes c
                                ON c.id = v.cliente_id
                            WHERE MONTH( v.data_vendas ) = :month AND YEAR( v.data_vendas ) = :year' );

    $stmt->bindValue( ':month', $config['MES_DADOS'] );
    $stmt->bindValue( ':year', $config['ANO_DADOS'] );
    $stmt->bindValue( ':prevMonth', $prevMonth );

    $result = $stmt->execute();

    if($result !== false)
    {
        $numClientes = $stmt->fetchAll( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC )[0];
        echo "Total de vendas no mes: {$numClientes['totalVendas']}.<br />";
        echo "{$numClientes['totalVendasCadastroAtual']} clientes se cadastraram no mes de {$config['MES_DADOS']} e compraram esse mes.<br />";
        echo "{$numClientes['totalVendasCadastroAnterior']} clientes se cadastraram no mes de {$prevMonth} e compraram esse mes.<br />";
    }
}
catch( PDOException $ex )
{
    die( $ex->getMessage() );
}
```

Comment: Oi, muito obrigada. Ficou muito bom. Eu tenho apenas uma dúvida. Nesta consulta, como posso adicionar o total de compras, dos clientes que sobraram. Ou seja, fizeram compra neste mes, mas se cadastraram no sistema no mes, 4, 3, 2 etc, ou seja, todos que sobraram pra tras

Comment: Editei a resposta com o total do mês.